# PrimeNG Calendar - appendTo something else than body

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

**The problem**:
I am using a p-calendar, in a narrow HTML page : very low height. In that case, the calendar just hide the input field with a bad positionning

**Step to reproduce** :

- go to https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar
- Resize the navigator window with a low value height
- Open some calendar
- Or go to blitzstack here and play with the console height: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-stwowy

**Result** : 
Calendar is covering the input field:
[image]

**Solutions I am trying**

- I tried [appendTo]="'body'" : it's not working, the calendar has a position that still hide the input field
- I want to append the calendar overlay to another thing:

```
    <ng-template #attachMe0></ng-template>
    <div id="attachMe1">
        <p-calendar #calendarRangeFacture
                    [(ngModel)]="rangeDates"
                    appendTo="attachMe0">
        </p-calendar>
    </div>

    <button class="blue-button" pButton  (click)="doIt()" label="OK"></button>
    <span id="attachMe2"></span>
    <div id="attachMe3"></div>
    <ng-template id="attachMe4"></ng-template>
    <ng-template #attachMe5></ng-template>
```

Here i have put many example of things I tried. All attachMe produce the same error :
[image]

Any Idea ? What am I doing wrong please ?

**[EDIT]** BLITZSTACK to play: https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-stwowy 
Just make sure the console goes high enuff:
[image]

Comment: try `appendTo="body"` with out the square bracket `[ ]`

Comment: Thanks for info, but of course I tried ```appendTo="body"``` and ```[appendTo]="body"``` and ```[appendTo]="'body'"``` (with single quotes) and every other combinations. nothing works I still have the problem

Comment: how about setting a margin-top for the date picker panel something like [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhqxej)

Comment: Target element to attach the overlay, valid values are "body" or a local **ng-template** variable of another element.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm thanks for this, but Below code show other html elements i tried among which you can see 2 ng-templates. Same error with them

Comment: @All : added a blitzstack so you can tried all by your self and play with all attacheMe elements

Comment: @Deunz Did you find a way to do this ?

Comment: No sorry, i don't work on that project anymore, and this problem remains on it :)

Comment: Somehow appendTo="body" is not working. But appendTo can also be used with expression.
For example appendTo="@(body)"

Answer (score 4):

You can use [baseZIndex] value with appendTo="body".

Answer (score 1):

I have two Angular applications, and both have popups which needed the PrimeNG calendar component in them, and I didn't want the calendar to be cropped.

In the first app, simply adding this line worked fine - but - the popup was in the same .html page as the rest of the webpage.  (So, it was one .html page, with both the regular page, and the markup for the popup.)

```
appendTo="body"
```

In the second app, the webpage opened a popup as a *separate component*, and there, this `appendTo` doesn't work at all.

[image]

So, my Answer to this question is that, yes, `appendTo` is a solution.... but annoyingly, it will not work all the time with Angular apps.

And you might have to make your Angular apps uglier, by moving the popup markup into the "calling" webpage, to make it work properly.

Answer (score 0):

Version -> Using in my application

- Angular CLI: 7.3.9
- Node: 12.13.1
- Angular: 7.2.15
- Primeng: 7.1.3

> Try to use appendTo like this, it works for me

```
 [appendTo]="'body'"
```

Still fixing, always calendar will be open in bottom!